# How does Javascript module know about display elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, module-pattern

I'm trying to implement the Module design pattern with Javascript.

One of the main problems I'm running into in my head is whether or not a module should render itself or alternatively how it knows about HTML elements which it's controlling. From what I've read a module should be entirely encapsulated which makes me ask - should a selector be passed to the module to specify which DOM element it's being used for or should the module output its own markup to ensure full control.

One of my main problems with these design patterns is that my mind won't let me actually write code unless I feel like I'm implementing the pattern 100% correctly...

Answer (score 0):

There is no absolutely correct way of writing the things. It's not only back and white and in most of the cases depends on the specific case. I don't know your project, but I'll suggest to make the things as flexible as possible. If you create the DOM element inside the module this means that it will be responsible for one more thing, which is against the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Also it is a good practice to put the template operation out of the javascript logic. And of course, don't be afraid to write something, even it looks wrong for you. As soon as you have the module working you will be able to spot the problems.